# Shadows/Transparency in 3D JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

I am creating an app which needs to graph a plane (I am using Rectangle) and points (I used Spheres). I tested it out in a separate project (pic 1), and as you can see, there is a shadow/transparency effect on the spheres since the graph goes through them. When I try to implement the same functions with the exact same numbers in my actual application, I get the second picture. There is no "shadow" anymore even though I am sure the rectangle goes through the points. What would be the cause of this issue and how can I fix it ?

What I have tried and does not work :

- Add the Rectangle first, then the points and vice-versa
- Change the opacity of the Rectangle (it is set to 0.5 in both)
- Remove the AmbientLight

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Here is the code that gave me the first picture :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.AmbientLight;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GraphFX3D extends Application {

    double mousePosX;
    double mousePosY;
    double mouseOldX;
    double mouseOldY;
    double mouseDeltaX;
    double mouseDeltaY;

    private static final double CAMERA_INITIAL_DISTANCE = -300;
    private static final double CAMERA_INITIAL_X_ANGLE = 0;
    private static final double CAMERA_INITIAL_Y_ANGLE = 0;
    private static final double CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP = 0.1;
    private static final double CAMERA_FAR_CLIP = 1000.0;

    final Xform root = new Xform();
    final Xform scalable = new Xform();

    final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    final Xform cameraXform = new Xform();
    final Xform cameraXform2 = new Xform();
    final Xform cameraXform3 = new Xform();

    Box map = bigCube();

    Color white = Color.web("#E7EBEE");
    Color grey = Color.web("#333234");
    Color red = Color.web("#DF5C58");
    Color yellow = Color.web("#F2C15F");
    Color blue = Color.web("#1985A1");

    ObservableList<Node> axisList;
    ObservableList<Node> thingsToGraphList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Node> labelsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        axisList = getAxis();
        this.update();

        Point3D p1 = new Point3D(30, 0, 0);
        Point3D p2 = new Point3D(0, -40, 0);
        Point3D p3 = new Point3D(0, 0, -50);


        this.addPoint(p1);
        this.addPoint(p2);
        this.addPoint(p3);
        this.addPlane(p1.getX(), p2.getY(), p3.getZ());

        Scale mirror = new Scale(1, -1, -1);
        scalable.getTransforms().add(mirror);

        root.getChildren().add(scalable);

        buildCamera();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, true);
        scene.setFill(grey);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case Z:
                        scalable.setScale(1);
                        camera.setTranslateX(0);
                        camera.setTranslateY(0);
                        cameraXform2.t.setX(0.0);
                        cameraXform2.t.setY(0.0);
                        camera.setTranslateZ(CAMERA_INITIAL_DISTANCE);
                        cameraXform.ry.setAngle(CAMERA_INITIAL_Y_ANGLE);
                        cameraXform.rx.setAngle(CAMERA_INITIAL_X_ANGLE);
                        break;
                    case V:
                        scalable.setVisible(!scalable.isVisible());
                        break;
                    case UP:
                        cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() - 1);
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() + 1);
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() + 1);
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() - 1);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        scene.setOnScroll((e) -> {

            double zoomRatio = 1;
            if(e.getDeltaY() > 0) {
                zoomRatio = 1.05;
            } else {
                zoomRatio = 0.95;
            }

            double scale = scalable.getScale() * zoomRatio;
            scalable.setScale(scale);
        });

        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
                mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                mouseOldX = mousePosX;
                mouseOldY = mousePosY;
                mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX);
                mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);

                if (me.isControlDown()) {}
                if (me.isShiftDown()) {}

                if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown() && me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    camera.setTranslateX(camera.getTranslateX() + mouseDeltaX);
                    camera.setTranslateY(camera.getTranslateY() + mouseDeltaY);
                }
                else if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() + mouseDeltaX);
                    cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() - mouseDeltaY);
                }
                else if (me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    double z = camera.getTranslateZ();
                    double newZ = z + mouseDeltaX;
                    camera.setTranslateZ(newZ);
                }
                else if (me.isMiddleButtonDown()) {
                    cameraXform2.t.setX(cameraXform2.t.getX() + mouseDeltaX);
                    cameraXform2.t.setY(cameraXform2.t.getY() + mouseDeltaY);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public Box bigCube() {
        map = new Box(400, 400, 400);
        map.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        return map;
    }

    private ObservableList<Node> getAxis() {

        ObservableList<Node> axisList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Cylinder xAxis = new Cylinder(1.5, 3000);
        xAxis.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.RED));
        xAxis.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90, 0, 0, 0, new Point3D(0, 0, 1)));
        Cylinder yAxis = new Cylinder(1.5, 3000);
        yAxis.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.GREEN));
        yAxis.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90, 0, 0, 0, new Point3D(0, 1, 0)));
        Cylinder zAxis = new Cylinder(1.5, 3000);
        zAxis.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
        zAxis.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90, 0, 0, 0, new Point3D(1, 0, 0)));


        Xform axes = new Xform();
        axes.getChildren().addAll(xAxis, yAxis, zAxis);
        axisList.add(axes);

        return axisList;
    }

    public void addPoint(Point3D point) {
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(3);
        sphere.setTranslateX(point.getX());
        sphere.setTranslateY(point.getY());
        sphere.setTranslateZ(point.getZ());
        addPointToList(sphere);
    }

    public void addPlane(double x, double y, double z) {
        Rectangle plane = new Rectangle(-500, -500, 1000, 1000);

        Point3D m = new Point3D(x/2, y/2, 0); // Midpoint between x and y
        double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(m.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(m.getY(), 2) + Math.pow(z, 2)); // Distance between m and z
        double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(z / d)); // Angle it needs to rotate
        Point3D vector = new Point3D(-x, y, 0); // "Axis" of rotation, aka vector from x to y

        if (x * y < 0) { // If the coordinates are a bit weird we need to do this
            angle = 360 - angle;
        }

        Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle, m.getX(), m.getY(), 0, vector);
        plane.getTransforms().addAll(rotate);

        addPlaneToList(plane);
    }

    public void addPointToList(Sphere sphere) {
        thingsToGraphList.add(sphere);
        switch (thingsToGraphList.size()) {
            case 1:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(red));
                break;
            case 2:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(yellow));
                break;
            case 3:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(blue));
                break;
            default:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(yellow));
                break;
        }
        this.update();
    }

    public void addPlaneToList(Rectangle rectangle) {
        rectangle.setOpacity(0.5);
        thingsToGraphList.add(rectangle);
        switch (thingsToGraphList.size()) {
            case 1:
                rectangle.setFill(red);
                break;
            case 2:
                rectangle.setFill(yellow);
                break;
            case 3:
                rectangle.setFill(blue);
                break;
            default:
                rectangle.setFill(white);
                break;
        }
        this.update();
    }

    private void setCameraFromViewPoint(double x, double y, double z) {
        double zTranslate
                = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2));

        double ryAngle, rxAngle;

        if (zTranslate > 0) {
            ryAngle = -Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, z));
            rxAngle
                    = -Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(y / zTranslate));
        } else {
            ryAngle = 0;
            rxAngle = 0;
        }

        camera.setTranslateZ(-zTranslate);
        cameraXform.ry.setAngle(ryAngle);
        cameraXform.rx.setAngle(rxAngle);
    }

    private void buildCamera() {
        root.getChildren().add(cameraXform);
        cameraXform.getChildren().add(cameraXform2);
        cameraXform2.getChildren().add(cameraXform3);
        cameraXform3.getChildren().add(camera);

        camera.setFieldOfView(90);

        camera.setNearClip(CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP);
        camera.setFarClip(CAMERA_FAR_CLIP);
        setCameraFromViewPoint(100, 100, 300);
    }

    public void update() {
        scalable.getChildren().clear();
        scalable.getChildren().add(new AmbientLight());
        scalable.getChildren().addAll(axisList);
        scalable.getChildren().add(map);
        scalable.getChildren().addAll(thingsToGraphList);
        scalable.getChildren().addAll(labelsList);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the code that gave me the second picture (the graph is stored in Pane and then added to a scene) :

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Scale;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import pack.View.Customs.CustomText;

public class Graph extends Group {

    double mousePosX, mousePosY;
    double mouseOldX, mouseOldY;
    double mouseDeltaX, mouseDeltaY;

    private static final double CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP = 0.1;
    private static final double CAMERA_FAR_CLIP = 1000.0;

    final Xform root = new Xform();
    final Xform scalable = new Xform();

    final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    final Xform cameraXform = new Xform();
    final Xform cameraXform2 = new Xform();
    final Xform cameraXform3 = new Xform();

    Box map = bigCube();

    Color white = Color.web("#E7EBEE");
    Color grey = Color.web("#333234");
    Color red = Color.web("#DF5C58");
    Color yellow = Color.web("#F2C15F");
    Color blue = Color.web("#1985A1");

    private int a = 0; // Serves as a counter to know which color should the added element be

    ObservableList<Node> axisList;
    ObservableList<Node> thingsToGraphList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Node> labelsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public Graph() {
        axisList = getAxis();
        this.update();

        Point3D p1 = new Point3D(30, 0, 0);
        Point3D p2 = new Point3D(0, -40, 0);
        Point3D p3 = new Point3D(0, 0, -50);

        this.addPlane(p1.getX(), p2.getY(), p3.getZ(), "fygu");

        this.addPoint(p1);
        this.addPoint(p2);
        this.addPoint(p3);

        Scale mirror = new Scale(1, -1, -1);
        scalable.getTransforms().add(mirror);
        root.getChildren().add(scalable);
        buildCamera();

        SubScene scene = new SubScene(root, 500, 525);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        this.getChildren().add(scene);

        scene.setOnScroll((e) -> {
            double zoomRatio = 1;
            if (e.getDeltaY() > 0 && scalable.getScale() < 5) {
                zoomRatio = 1.05;
            } else if (e.getDeltaY() < 0 && scalable.getScale() > 0.5) {
                zoomRatio = 0.95;
            }
            map.setScaleX(map.getScaleX() / zoomRatio);
            map.setScaleY(map.getScaleY() / zoomRatio);
            map.setScaleZ(map.getScaleZ() / zoomRatio);
            double scale = scalable.getScale() * zoomRatio;
            scalable.setScale(scale);
        });

        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
                mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
            }
        });

        scene.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                mouseOldX = mousePosX;
                mouseOldY = mousePosY;
                mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
                mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
                mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX);
                mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);
                if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown() && me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    camera.setTranslateX(camera.getTranslateX() + mouseDeltaX);
                    camera.setTranslateY(camera.getTranslateY() + mouseDeltaY);
                } else if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                    cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() + mouseDeltaX);
                    cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() - mouseDeltaY);
                } else if (me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                    double z = camera.getTranslateZ();
                    double newZ = z + mouseDeltaX;
                    camera.setTranslateZ(newZ);
                } else if (me.isMiddleButtonDown()) {
                    cameraXform2.t.setX(cameraXform2.t.getX() + mouseDeltaX);
                    cameraXform2.t.setY(cameraXform2.t.getY() + mouseDeltaY);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Box bigCube() {
        map = new Box(400, 400, 400);
        map.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        return map;
    }

    private ObservableList<Node> getAxis() {

        ObservableList<Node> axisList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Cylinder xAxis = new Cylinder(1.5, 3000);
        xAxis.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.RED));
        xAxis.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90, 0, 0, 0, new Point3D(0, 0, 1)));
        Cylinder yAxis = new Cylinder(1.5, 3000);
        yAxis.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.GREEN));
        yAxis.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90, 0, 0, 0, new Point3D(0, 1, 0)));
        Cylinder zAxis = new Cylinder(1.5, 3000);
        zAxis.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
        zAxis.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(90, 0, 0, 0, new Point3D(1, 0, 0)));

        Xform axes = new Xform();
        axes.getChildren().addAll(xAxis, yAxis, zAxis);
        axisList.add(axes);

        return axisList;
    }

    public void addPoint(Point3D point) {
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(3);
        sphere.setTranslateX(point.getX());
        sphere.setTranslateY(point.getY());
        sphere.setTranslateZ(point.getZ());
        //createPointLabel(point);
        addPointToList(sphere);
    }

    public void addPlane(double x, double y, double z, String equation) {
        Rectangle plane = new Rectangle(-500, -500, 1000, 1000);

        Point3D m = new Point3D(x/2, y/2, 0); // Midpoint between x and y
        double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(m.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(m.getY(), 2) + Math.pow(z, 2)); // Distance between m and z
        double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(z / d)); // Angle it needs to rotate
        Point3D vector = new Point3D(-x, y, 0); // "Axis" of rotation, aka vector from x to y

        if (x * y < 0) { // If the coordinates are a bit weird we need to do this
            angle = 360 - angle;
        }

        Rotate rotate = new Rotate(angle, m.getX(), m.getY(), 0, vector);
        plane.getTransforms().addAll(rotate);

        createPlaneLabel(equation);
        addPlaneToList(plane);
    }

    public void addPointToList(Sphere sphere) {
        thingsToGraphList.add(sphere);
        switch (thingsToGraphList.size()) {
            case 1:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(red));
                break;
            case 2:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(yellow));
                break;
            case 3:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(blue));
                break;
            default:
                sphere.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(yellow));
                break;
        }
        this.update();
    }

    public void addPlaneToList(Rectangle rectangle) {
        a++;
        rectangle.setOpacity(0.5);
        thingsToGraphList.add(rectangle);
        switch (a) {
            case 1:
                rectangle.setFill(red);
                break;
            case 2:
                rectangle.setFill(yellow);
                break;
            case 3:
                rectangle.setFill(blue);
                break;
            default:
                rectangle.setFill(white);
                break;
        }
        this.update();
    }

    private void createPointLabel(Point3D point) {
        Text label = new CustomText("(" + point.getX() + ", " + point.getY() + ", " + point.getZ() + ")");
        label.setScaleY(-1);
        label.setTranslateX(point.getX());
        label.setTranslateY(point.getY());
        label.setTranslateZ(point.getZ());
        labelsList.add(label);
    }

    private void createLineLabel(Point3D point1, Point3D point2) {
        Text label = new CustomText("l(t) = (" + (int) point1.getX() + ", " + (int) point1.getY() + ", " + (int) point1.getZ() + ") +\nt <" + (int) point2.getX() + ", " + (int) point2.getY() + ", " + (int) point2.getZ() + ">");
        label.setScaleY(-1);
        label.setTranslateX(point1.getX());
        label.setTranslateY(point1.getY());
        label.setTranslateZ(point1.getZ());
        labelsList.add(label);
    }

    private void createPlaneLabel(String equation) {
        Text label = new Text(equation);
        label.setScaleY(-1);
        labelsList.add(label);
    }

    private void setCameraFromViewPoint(double x, double y, double z) {
        double zTranslate
                = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2));

        double ryAngle, rxAngle;

        if (zTranslate > 0) {
            ryAngle = -Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, z));
            rxAngle
                    = -Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(y / zTranslate));
        } else {
            ryAngle = 0;
            rxAngle = 0;
        }

        camera.setTranslateZ(-zTranslate);
        cameraXform.ry.setAngle(ryAngle);
        cameraXform.rx.setAngle(rxAngle);
    }

    private void buildCamera() {
        root.getChildren().add(cameraXform);
        cameraXform.getChildren().add(cameraXform2);
        cameraXform2.getChildren().add(cameraXform3);
        cameraXform3.getChildren().add(camera);

        camera.setFieldOfView(90);

        camera.setNearClip(CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP);
        camera.setFarClip(CAMERA_FAR_CLIP);
        setCameraFromViewPoint(100, 100, 300);
    }

    public void update() {
        scalable.getChildren().clear();
        scalable.getChildren().add(new AmbientLight());
        scalable.getChildren().addAll(axisList);
        scalable.getChildren().add(map);
        scalable.getChildren().addAll(thingsToGraphList);
        scalable.getChildren().addAll(labelsList);
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaFX 3D supports neither of those features.

Comment: @jewelsea sorry if that was unclear but I am not using JavaFX3D. I am using JavaFX, in 3D. I need my second picture to achieve the same effect as in the first picture, so JavaFX does have this feature since I did it in the first picture right ?

Comment: Yes, I understand the library you are using, I mean the [same library](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/jfxpub-3d_graphics.htm).  Even if you were able to get something that appeared right once, I don't believe that correct 3D transparency and shadow support are in the feature set for 3D in JavaFX.  You can see a related open feature request for transparency support [JDK-8170852 Order-independent transparency for 3D objects](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170852).

Comment: For 3D shadow support, I don't know if there is a feature request. Even if created, [it would probably not be implemented in the core 3D features of the JavaFX library](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/64517/what-is-required-for-casting-shadows-in-javafx-8-3d).